# Cucumber - NullPointerexception when Using nonstatic webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java

There are 3 pages 
1. Homepage - This is default page 
2. Login Page - Appears on click of Sign In Link 
3. My AccountPage - Appears after login

Note: When I Use Non static Webdriver, it  works fine till login i.e launches Homepage successfully , then navigates to login page and enter credentials and login successfully to display My Account page 
Now after login when I try to access the [page heading element] of My Accountpage it throws null pointer exception [Indicated in the code of MyAccountPageObject class] 
Note: 1. When I Use Static webdriver code runs successfully but null pointer exception on nonstatic webdriver 
2. I have designed my Selenium-testng-maven framework in similar way [using nonstatic webdriver and it runs fine]

Below is the entire code

HomePageObject

```
public class HomePageObject extends 
TestBase{        
  public HomePageObject (WebDriver driverObj){
      this.driverObj = driverObj;
  }  
 public SignInPageObject  navigateToSignInPage(){
     System.out.println("In navigateToSignInPage"); 
     driverObj.navigate().to("http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account#account-creation");
     SignInPageObject signInPageObj = PageFactory.initElements(driverObj, SignInPageObject.class);
      return signInPageObj 
 }
```

}

SignInPageObject

```
public class SignInPageObject extends TestBase{

 @FindBy(id  = "email")
 public static WebElement SignIn_Email_TB;

 @FindBy(id  = "passwd")
 public static WebElement SignIn_Password_TB;

 @FindBy(id = "SubmitLogin")
 public static WebElement SignIn_Btn;

 @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id = 'center_column']/h1")
 public static WebElement MyAccountHeading_Lnk;

public MyAccountPageObject cucumberValidateLogin(String emailAddress, String password) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("In Cucumber Validatelogin method");     
        SignInPageObject.SignIn_Email_TB.sendKeys(emailAddress);
        SignInPageObject.SignIn_Password_TB.sendKeys(password);
        SignInPageObject.SignIn_Btn.click();
        MyAccountPageObject myAccountPageObj = PageFactory.initElements(driverObj, MyAccountPageObject.class);
        return myAccountPageObj;
    }
```

}

My featureFile

```
Feature: To test the Login functionality 
Background:  
Given Login page is displayed

Scenario: Title, Heading, Subheading and Breadcrumb validation on SignIn page
 Then I Check the Presence of Page Title
  """
  Login - My Store
  """

Scenario Outline: user login   
When User enter valid "<EmailAddress>" and "<Password>" on Login Page , Clicking on Signin Button should display My Account Page  
And user Closes the browser

Examples: Login credentials
  | EmailAddress          | Password  |
  | abcd@gmail.com        | Qwertyui1 |
```

SignInTest

```
 public class SignInTest extends 
 SignInPageObject{

HomePageObject homeObj;
MyAccountPageObject myAccountPageObj;
SignInPageObject signInPageObj;
String actualMyAccountpageHeading;

@Before()
public void before() throws Exception { 
    System.out.println("navigate to Homepage");
    homeObj = gm_OpenApp("CH", "http://automationpractice.com/index.php"); //This method in testbase
}

@After()
public void after() throws Exception {      
    driverObj.quit();   
}

@Given("^Login page is displayed$")
 public void Login_page_is_displayed(){   
    System.out.println("*******Now navigate to login page*******");
    signInPageObj = homeObj.navigateToSignInPage();  
    System.out.println("*******Login page is in display*******");
};
@Then("^I Check the Presence of Page Title$")
public void I_Check_the_Presence_of_Page_Title(String text){
 System.out.println(text);
 System.out.println(driverObj.getTitle());
};

@When("^User enter valid \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\" on Login Page, Clicking on Signin Button displays My Account Page$")
public void User_enter_valid_Email_and_password_on_login_page_Click_on_Signin_Button(String emailAddress, String password) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    myAccountPageObj = signInPageObj.cucumberValidateLogin(emailAddress, password);
            WebElement myAccountPageheadingEle = myAccountPageObj.MyAccount_PageHeading_Txt; 
            //--> This above statement causing error null pointer exception for the webelement listed on MyAccountPageObject            
            //Assert code to follow     

}
@Then("^user Closes the browser$")
public void user_Closes_the_browser() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    System.out.println("Closing Now");

};
```

MyAccountPageObject

```
public class MyAccountPageObject extends 
SignInPageObject{

//MyAccountPageTitle_Txt
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id = 'center_column']/h1")
public static WebElement MyAccount_PageHeading_Txt;  //WebElement1

//MyAccount_Breadcrumb_txt
@FindBy(xpath = "//span[@class = 'navigation_page']")
public static WebElement MyAccount_Breadcrumb_txt; //WebElement2

public MyAccountPageObject (){
    System.out.println("My Account Page launched");
    //--> This text gets printed when I Navigate to myAccount page but while accessing 
    //any of the abovve 2 webelements it throws null pointer exception
}

}
```

TestBase

```
public class TestBase extends SignInRunnerTest{ 

 //==>> My Code is working when I extend testbase to runnertest .. this is 
   not good practice because
 there will be many runnertests and testbase will be only1 so  I dont want 
  to testbase to extend the runnertest..what modification I will have to 
   do.. trying my best but unable to achieve to conclusion..//

public HomePageObject gm_OpenApp(String BrowserName, String URL)throws Exception{
    System.out.println("In gm_OpenAp Method");              
    gm_LaunchBrowser(BrowserName);      
    gm_OpenURL(URL);        
    System.out.println("Now Homepage is in display");       
    HomePageObject homeObj = PageFactory.initElements(driverObj, HomePageObject.class); 
    return homeObj;
}
```

}

SignInTestRunnerTest

```
@CucumberOptions(
strict = true,
features = { "src/test/resources/featurefiles/Autoprac/SignInTestA1.feature" }, 
    glue = {"samplecucumberproject"},       
    plugin = {"html:target/cucumber-html-report"},
    monochrome = true,
    dryRun = false
    )
public class SignInTestRunnerTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    public  WebDriver driverObj;     
    public static String Browser;
    public static String URL;
    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    @Parameters({ "Browser", "URL"})
    public void getBrowser(String Browser, String URL) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("SignIn Get Browser");
        this.Browser=Browser;
        this.URL = URL;
}
}
```

TestNG

```
  test name="Regression Test-CH" 
    <parameter name="Browser" value="CH" ></parameter>
    <parameter name="URL" value="http://automationpractice.com/index.php"></parameter>
    <classes>
        <class name="testrunner.SignInTestRunnerTest"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Comment: Looks like your MyAccountTestObject extends to BaseTest (via SignInPageObject), and you don't initiate webdriver on that pages. You may need to similar code like in HomePageObject.

Comment: Did the same and it woked... Thx. Now another challenge is -- how to pass browser and URL from testng.xml to all the test runners.  <br> I achieved this for 1 test runner  where I extended my base class to the test runner [BASECLASS EXTENS TESTRUNNER] and using @BeforeMethod in SignInTestRunnerTest and passing parameters from testNg.xml. <br> since there will be multiple testrunner so in that case java wont allow me to extend muliple testrunners to baseclass. <br>How to get this done?? <br>Please refer my Baseclass testRunner and testng.xml